# Conflic version sdk flutter (dart)

Tags: flutter, sdk

I would greatly appreciate your help. I cloned project Flutter from github, when I ran "pub get" that show message is
`The lower bound of "sdk: '>=2.0.0-dev.68.0 <3.1.0'" must be 2.12.0' or higher to enable null safety. The current Dart SDK (3.1.0) only supports null safety` .

Note that I am not a professional (I try to develop my own app) so I would really appreciate your help.

I thank you for your help !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you have Flutter version "3.13.0" (or higher) installed, but this project is using an older version.
Try using the smaller Flutter version, I think "3.10.6" should work, because it uses Dart SDK "3.0.6" (it fits the restrictions).
The specific version can be downloaded from the [official website](https://docs.flutter.dev/release/archive) or you can use [FVM](https://fvm.app/) to have multiple versions locally and switch between them as needed.